# How many bitstrings of length n contain an equal number of zeros and ones?

Tags: combinatorics, binary

> How many bitstrings of length n contain an equal number of zeros and ones?

#### Progress

Does $n!/2$ work as a solution since we know $n$ is even? For example, 000111 rearranged, $6!/2$?

What method is used to isolate strings with equal ones and zeros?

Comment: If you show what you have tried perhaps someone can provide a useful hint based on your work. Most problems can be solved in several ways. A hint based on a method of doing the problem that is completely different from your way of thinking about the problem may not be as useful as a hint based on your ideas.  After you can do the problem in one way knowing a second way can be useful too.

Comment: @Hux: I rolled back your edit because wrong $\neq$ bad. Feel free to edit back, but on MSE we (at least most of us) are of the opinion that an incorrect attempt is *much* better than no attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you know exactly how many 0's and 1's you have; you merely need to decide which positions to put the 0's in (the remainder get 1's).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you need to decide "the number of ways of placing n/2 identical items in n spaces" as placing the ones will naturally give you the places of the zeros (or vice versa).

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is odd, then there can be no strings that satisfy the criterion. If $n$ is even, then exactly $\frac{n}{2}$ of the bits will be $1$.  How will you choose which $\frac{n}{2}$ of $n$ bits receive the ones?

Note also that swapping the position of two $1$'s within the sequence yields the same sequence, and should not be counted twice.

Comment: I think you need some editing here.

Comment: Thanks @tom10.  I had to read it aloud before I could see it.  So much for proofreading.

Answer (score 0):

You have ${n \choose n/2}$ possibilities to choose the positions where the $n/2$ 0's are placed. Obviously $n$ must be even.

$n!/2$ does not work for $n=2$, since you have $2$ ways to arrange the bitstring, $01$ and $10$.

Answer (score 0):

${n \choose n/2}$.

There's $n$ places to put $n/2$ things.